# Sublime syntax highlighting not working for wrongly typed PHP built-in functions

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 version 3.2.2, Build 3211.

The issue is that Sublime syntax highlighting does not work for wrongly typed PHP built-in functions. I want it to behave like Notepad++ and some other code editors where If you mistakenly type wrong PHP built-in functions then editor considers it as a normal plain text. So you are aware of typo and just in case if you don't exactly remember the function name. You can rectify mistake as soon as you see that code color didn't change to what they are set for reserved keywords.

I am taking an example of PHP built-in string function `strlen()`.

**In Notepad++**

Here I deliberately typed `strlen` to `strle` to show you what I meant. Function name color turns to black:

[image]

When I type correct function name, the function name color becomes blue:

[image]

**In Sublime Text 3**

Wrong function name is still blue. You can't say it is typed right or wrong:

[image]

You can see that wrong PHP function does not change the color. So I can't figure out when I unintentionally type wrong function in large code. How can we fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is [color scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/search/color%20scheme)-dependent. I use the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (nb: I am its author), and your code looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the upper snippet with `strle`, the function name is in green, which all generic (i.e., non built-in) functions are. The relevant [scope](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#scope_rules:ver-3.2) is `meta.function-call.php variable.function.php`, which indicates as much.

In the lower snippet where `strlen` is spelled correctly, the syntax highlighting is completely different. The relevant scope there is `meta.function-call.php support.function.string.php`, indicating that the function is not only built-in, but it is a string function as well. If you wanted to, you could adjust your color scheme to highlight all string functions differently than other builtins.

I don't know what color scheme you are using, but it apparently doesn't differentiate between different types of functions. Unfortunately, unless you are gifted in both reading JSON and interpreting Sublime scopes in your head, there really isn't a way to see if a given color scheme supports this differentiation or not. I designed Neon with the goal of making as many language constructs as possible look as good as possible, but not all (in fact, not many) color scheme authors share this goal, so if you don't prefer Neon you'll have to look around some. There are currently in the neighborhood of 300 different [color schemes on Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/color%20scheme). If you'd rather alter your current color scheme *and the [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html#ver-3.2) don't answer all your questions*, just post a new question and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm using Dreamweaver color scheme. Here's the link: https://github.com/mghweb/SublimeDreamweaver. Since I have been using DW for a long time since I started coding so no other color scheme looks nice and comfort to my eyes. I tweaked this color scheme as it had some flaws regarding HTML form tags etc. So the scope you talked about needs to be changed in my current color scheme? You were right that it is color scheme dependent because when I switched to Sixteen color scheme the color of misspelled PHP function changed.

Comment: One another question associated with color scheme is that can we make Sublime to highlight all occurrences of matching text. Currently it can only put border around the text?

Comment: @Sachin Ah yes, Dreamweaver. I used that back in the 90s at my first (paid) coding job... Anyways, yes, if you add separate scopes for `meta.function-call variable.function` and `meta.function-call support.function.string` (or just `meta.function-call support.function`) to your color scheme, you'll be fine. For your 2nd comment, can you write that up as a new question and include details about what exactly you're doing? Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know you tasted it too! These scopes solved my one problem but created some another. The new problem is that the function name doesn't change its color at the place where I am calling it. Now I am thinking to leave this tweak procedure as it is wasting my time and energy. Anyway, thanks for your help. And for my second comment question, I searched and found that in ST3 it is not yet possible.

Comment: @Sachin Check out ST4. You didn't say exactly what you were doing to create the outlines, but I know it has a number of new features for highlighting, as well as a ton of other stuff. I've been using it for over a year, since the first alpha builds were in private testing, and I love it.

Comment: There are so many things that are not possible with my theme... can't cover everything. So I'm giving up now. If I modify PHP syntax highlighting in my theme then JS is left and similarly some others. So I think its better to stick with default color scheme.

Comment: And yes you are right. ST4 has a tons of new features and improvements over ST3 but I don't have its registered version. I want to stick with ST3 for now.

Comment: Ok so after following your Neon theme and analyzing my custom DW theme, now I have started to make some modification as per my desire but I'm still having some issues in understanding and finding scopes. For example, I want to make <img> tag in a different color, I am trying with `<dict> <key>name</key> <string>HTML img tag</string> <key>scope</key> <string>entity.name.tag.img.html</string> <key>settings</key> <dict> <key>foreground</key> <string>#909</string> </dict> </dict>
` but it has no effect. What am I doing wrong here? Can I have reference to these all scopes used in .tmTheme file?

Comment: @Sachin `entity.name.tag.img.html` doesn't exist. I highly recommend installing [`ScopeHunter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) and [`ScopeAlways`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways) so you can see what scopes are active. You'd have to look through the `.sublime-syntax` file for the language you're using to see which scopes they define. There are some [suggested scope rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html), but not every language has all of them, and many languages extend that list as needed for their particular situations.

Comment: Oh OK, sorry. Actually my some other scopes e.g. `meta.tag.block.table.html`, `meta.tag.block.form.html` did work, so I thought this (for `img`) should also work. I went through ST official docs regarding this operation but they are not comprehensive and well understandable manner. Btw, what is the need of your suggested second package? First one is not enough?

Comment: @Sachin I like being able to see the scopes all the time, hence `ScopeAlways`, but `ScopeHunter` also allows me to copy the scope into my color scheme instead of having to remember the full thing and type it all out.

Comment: I am grateful to you from my heart. You came like an angel when I was giving up. And now you have rekindled the interest of modifying the color scheme. Thanks for that. Matt, I have a couple of questions regarding `.tmTheme` file. First is that what is the purpose of `uuid` in `<key>uuid</key>`? Is it necessary to have it in the file? How can I generate it my own?

Comment: Second question is about `scope`. Is it necessary to put entire `scope` string shown by `scopeHunter` in the `<string>...`? For example, in an HTML element, when I put my cursor on `style` in  `style="display:none;"`, `scopeHunter` says me `text.html.basic meta.tag.inline.any.html meta.attribute-with-value.style.html entity.other.attribute-name.style.html`. And if I only want to change the color of `style` attribute then using only the part `entity.other.attribute-name.style.html` is enough. So is it alright if I do so? Or is there any legitimate reason to write the entire `scope` string?

Comment: @Sachin I [created a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234301/chat-between-mattdmo-and-sachin) so we can go back and forth without the comments becoming a mile long. I'll try to answer your questions there.

Comment: Ok sure, we'll use that for our further conversation on this topic. Thanks.